# Compare two SQL Server databases with T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider we have a database for an windows application it's for 2 years ago, now we have changed many things in database so there is differences and we don't know what are the differences.

I don't want to use compare tools like Red Gate compare tool.

What's the best way to see new columns are in new database :

Query result like :

```
New Db Name | Schema | Table Name | Column Name | Default Value | IsNullable | DataType
NewDb       | dbo    | myTable    | newColumn   | ''            | No         | nvarchar(30)
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use schema compare in sql server data tools (free). It will also generate a change script for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Columns in old database but not in new , or default value, nullable and data type changed:**

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM [OldDb].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] t1
LEFT JOIN [NewDb].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] t2
ON t1.COLUMN_NAME= t2.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE t2.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL 
or
(t1.Table_name=t2.Table_name 
AND t1.column_name = t2.column_name 
AND (t1.data_type != t2.data_type 
or t1.is_nullable != t2.is_nullable
or t1.character_maximum_length != t2.character_maximum_length
or t1.column_default != t2.column_default))
ORDER BY t1.COLUMN_NAME
```

**Columns in new database but not in old :**

You can change [OldDb] place with [NewDb] in query

I wrote this question and answer because I've needed this and I've spent so much of time on this.

So I hope everyone can find and use this easily :).